# how to create an outbound interface with disabled event listener using automation script in ibm maximo

Tags: maximo

Is there a posibilities using an automation script that can generate an outbound payload even the event listener from publish channel is disabled?

I'm trying to create a automation script that can generate payload with disabled event listener from publish channel, but I don't have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to trigger a publish channel manually.  Here's a couple references.  HOWEVER:  I tried to set this up once and was unsuccessful, I did save the code with the comment "Doesn't work by the way, getting an out of bounds error on the line above"

```
from psdi.server import MXServer 
from psdi.security import UserInfo  
from psdi.util.logging import MXLogger 
from psdi.util.logging import MXLoggerFactory  
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants

server = MXServer.getMXServer()
userInfo = server.getUserInfo("MAXADMIN")
whereClause = "PMNUM = 'PM108688'"
server.lookup("MIC").exportData("<publish channel>", "<External System Name>", whereClause, userInfo, 1)
```

That said, there's few different references out there that suggests it works - the 2nd one below indicates in the comments that he got it working, just not  for JSON output.

[previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205324/trigger-maximo-mif-integration-of-object-using-automation-script)

[maxdeploy blog article](https://maximodeploy.blogspot.com/2020/05/invokecall-publish-channel.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

from psdi.iface.mic import PublishChannelCache

PublishChannelCache.getInstance().getPublishChannel("[PUBLISH_CHANNEL_NAME]").publish(mbo, True)

I talked a bit more on that here: https://blog.relia.app/2020/12/avoiding-recursion-filter-on-publish-channel/

Comment: If event listener from publish channel is disabled, call to publish channel from Automation Script would not be successful.